# PhpStorm: Nest or Group generated CSS files under source LESS file

Tags: css, less, phpstorm

Can PhpStorm hide generated CSS files under the LESS file?

Here is a screenshot of a WordPress theme:

[image]

I've found myself opening the `.css` file instead of the `.less` one on numerous occasions. Is there some way to group these files together so I never see the `.css` file? A bit like a closed folder, have to click the arrow to view generated file?

(I remember seeing a similar feature somewhere, not sure if it was in PhpStorm or another editor)

I did have LESS files in their own folder, but I still found myself opening the `.css` file from time to time by accident. It would be good to hide them completely.

Thanks!

Comment: The grouping is handled by File Watcher (if you have it configured and done it correctly) -- there are no other options (e.g. specify grouping rules manually etc) to do that ATM.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it seems to be (kinda?) working:

[image]

`style.less` nests `style.css` correctly, not sure why the others are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

It is called File Nesting and it’s available from the gear icon in the Project browser.

[image]